# Listar Base de Datos, Usuarios y Roles en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

verán tengo un servidor con varias base de datos, y necesito listar cada base de datos con sus usuarios y sus roles, con el siguiente script he conseguido listar los usuarios de cada bd que poseen un rol, pero necesito tambien listar aquellos que no tienen rol y no lo he conseguido, les agradeceré bastante si me pueden dar una mano. Saludos.

```
WITH RoleMembers (member_principal_id, role_principal_id) 
AS 
(
  SELECT 
   rm1.member_principal_id, 
   rm1.role_principal_id
  FROM sys.database_role_members rm1 (NOLOCK)
   UNION ALL
  SELECT 
   d.member_principal_id, 
   rm.role_principal_id
  FROM sys.database_role_members rm (NOLOCK)
   INNER JOIN RoleMembers AS d 
   ON rm.member_principal_id = d.role_principal_id
)
select distinct rp.name as database_role, mp.name as database_userl
from RoleMembers drm
  join sys.database_principals rp on (drm.role_principal_id = rp.principal_id)
  join sys.database_principals mp on (drm.member_principal_id = mp.principal_id)
order by rp.name
```

Answer (score 1):

Con este script obtienes lo que pides:

```
USE MASTER
    GO
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQLVerNo INT;
    SET @SQLVerNo = cast(substring(CAST(Serverproperty('ProductVersion') AS VARCHAR(50)) ,0,charindex('.',CAST(Serverproperty('ProductVersion') AS VARCHAR(50)) ,0)) as int);

    IF @SQLVerNo >= 9 
        IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 *
                   FROM Tempdb.sys.objects (nolock)
                   WHERE name LIKE '#TUser%')
            DROP TABLE #TUser
    ELSE
    IF @SQLVerNo = 8
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 *
                   FROM Tempdb.dbo.sysobjects (nolock)
                   WHERE name LIKE '#TUser%')
            DROP TABLE #TUser
    END

    CREATE TABLE #TUser (
        ServerName    varchar(256),
        DBName        SYSNAME,
        [Name]        SYSNAME,
        GroupName     SYSNAME NULL,
        LoginName     SYSNAME NULL,
        default_database_name  SYSNAME NULL,
        default_schema_name    VARCHAR(256) NULL,
        Principal_id  INT,
        [sid]         VARBINARY(85))

    IF @SQLVerNo = 8
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #TUser
        EXEC sp_MSForEachdb
        '
         SELECT 
           @@SERVERNAME,
           ''?'' as DBName,
           u.name As UserName,
           CASE WHEN (r.uid IS NULL) THEN ''public'' ELSE r.name END AS GroupName,
           l.name AS LoginName,
           NULL AS Default_db_Name,
           NULL as default_Schema_name,
           u.uid,
           u.sid
         FROM [?].dbo.sysUsers u
           LEFT JOIN ([?].dbo.sysMembers m 
           JOIN [?].dbo.sysUsers r
           ON m.groupuid = r.uid)
           ON m.memberuid = u.uid
           LEFT JOIN dbo.sysLogins l
           ON u.sid = l.sid
         WHERE u.islogin = 1 OR u.isntname = 1 OR u.isntgroup = 1
           /*and u.name like ''tester''*/
         ORDER BY u.name
        '
    END

    ELSE 
    IF @SQLVerNo >= 9
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #TUser
        EXEC sp_MSForEachdb
        '
         SELECT 
           @@SERVERNAME,
           ''?'',
           u.name,
           CASE WHEN (r.principal_id IS NULL) THEN ''public'' ELSE r.name END GroupName,
           l.name LoginName,
           l.default_database_name,
           u.default_schema_name,
           u.principal_id,
           u.sid
         FROM [?].sys.database_principals u
           LEFT JOIN ([?].sys.database_role_members m
           JOIN [?].sys.database_principals r 
           ON m.role_principal_id = r.principal_id)
           ON m.member_principal_id = u.principal_id
           LEFT JOIN [?].sys.server_principals l
           ON u.sid = l.sid
         WHERE u.TYPE <> ''R''
           /*and u.name like ''tester''*/
         order by u.name
         '
    END

    SELECT *
    FROM #TUser
    ORDER BY DBName,
     [name],
     GroupName

    DROP TABLE #TUser
    END
```

Fuente: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/list-all-usernames-roles-for-all-the-databases

Comment: La probé, pero no me ha dado resultados, viendo el script no se de donde saca "EXEC sp_MSForEachdb"

Comment: ¿No te ha dado resultados? Este script te lista todos los usuarios con su rol asociado para cada base de datos... a mi si que me ha funcionado. El procedimiento almacenado "sp_MSForEachdb" es propio de SQL Server, lo puedes encontrar en System Databases --> Programmability --> Stored Procedures --> System Stored Procedures

Comment: El Script si funciona, muchas gracias